# Excel Macro to calculate number of working days/hours for each month

Tags: vba, excel

I have a start date and end date in two columns. There are 12 other columns one for each month. I am trying to run a macro which gives the number of working hours/days for each month in those 12 columns based on the start and end date

Comment: Really want a macro? Why not an excel formula?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have holidays on saturdays and sundays, you can try the below formula,

`=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2,$G$2:$G$4)`

Where `G2:G4` is the holiday range. This is optional.
[image]

Excel has another function which allows you to alter your weekends,

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL (start_date, end_date, [weekend], [holidays])`

You can specify weekends and holidays as well. The below formula indicates that all days in a week are working days, (column E)

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,"0000000")`

If you have only 8 working hours a day, just multiply the difference with 8. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! There a a 100's of columns and I am trying to write a macro to update all the 12 columns automatically. I used the network days in my macro and tried to pass multiple holidays, then I got an error. But after I saved all the holidays in a different sheet and passed it to Network days it worked.

Comment: @LearningNew Great!! Please upvote and mark answer as correct if you found this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NetworkDays](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) formula for this.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(StartDate, EndDate, [Holidays])
```

If you don't want Excel to count bank holidays you will need to supply the formula with a list.

The number of working hours in a day isn't standard.  You will need to calculate this yourself (`Working Days * Working Hours in Day`).